# What is the difference between a list of tuples and a list of objects?

Tags: list, tuples

Please see I want list employee objects. So I have below two options.

1. `List<Tuple<int, string, string, string>>`
2. `List<Employee>`where Employee is class contains 4 properties.

My doubt is what should I use(tuple or list of employee object?
If it is `List<Employee>` then in which scenario I should use `List<Tuple<int, string, ...>>`.

Comment: They are both lists. 1 is a list of tuples, 2 is a list of Employee. Option 2 is more idiomatic in C#.

Comment: Seems to be opinion-based; perhaps 2. is easier to read?

Comment: At the moment, it's pretty unclear what you're asking here. If you want a list of employee objects, then what you want is `List<Employee>`. If you're asking "When should I create a new class rather than just using a tuple?", that's a very different question which is nothing to do with lists at all (but I'd agree with C Bauer's answer).

Comment: @molbdnilo, you are correct. Then which scenario I should use List of tuples. Could you please give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use tuples unless you are doing some sort of arithmetic operation where tuple would be an acceptable and widely understood method of supplying values. Tuples make it a maintenance nightmare for anyone who is not familiar with your process as you built it.

Edit: Think about the difference between seeing:

```
var employeeList = DAL.getEmployees();
var activeEmployees = employeeList.Where(employee => employee.IsActive);
```

vs

```
var employeeTuple = DAL.getEmployees();
var activeEmployees = employeeTuple.Where(employee => employee.Item3);
```

In the second example, I know THAT you created an active employee list, but I don't know HOW you did it.

Answer (score 0):

That's rather obvious. If you already have the `Employee` class then using `List<Employee>` is straightforward:

```
List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
list.Add( e );

...

Employee e = list.Where( i => i.Name == "John" ).FirstOrDefault();
```

whereas using `List<Tuple<...>>` is at least cumbersome:

```
List<Tuple<....>> list = new List<Tuple<....>>();
list.Add( new Tuple<...>( e.Name, e.Surname, e.Whateverelse, e.YetAnother ) );

...

// retrieve the tuple
var tuple = list.Where( i => i.Item1 == "John" ); 
// make Employee out of it
Employee e = new Employee( e.Item1, e.Item2, e.Item3, e.Item4 );
```